# Clarification on a step in Erdős's probabilistic proof for the lower bound of Ramsey Numbers?

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory, probabilistic-method

Generally I understand this argument, but I would like a more complete proof that the "best chance" you'll get at finding a complete monochromatic subgraph is if we treat each complete subgraph independently.

This intuitively makes sense, since these subgraphs may "interfere" with each other by sharing edges in the larger graph. However, I have not seen a hard proof that this interference will necessarily lower the probability of finding a complete monochromatic subgraph.

Comment: Well, so where is the proof?

Comment: I mean it's all over the internet, but I figured it out thanks.

Comment: Sure, but next time include as much context as possible. You can't expect us to read the question and go flipping through books or websites until we find the proof you're talking about.

Comment: To be honest I just don't know how to use Latex...but I'll post a link next time.

Answer (score 1):

The simple probability theorem that I was searching for was the Union Bound.